# JTable ImageIcon and String

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable, imageicon

I want to create a `JTable` where in the cells there could be an `ImageIcon`, `String` or both. I've already tried solutions like `table.setvalue()` or just adding the `Icon` to the `Object Array` for creating the `JTable`.

```
for (int n = 0; n < tableHeight; n++) {
  for (int m = 0; m < tableWidth; m++) {
    if ((n + m) == labelArray.size()) {
      break;
    }

    if (labelArray.get(n + m).iconMode) {  //iconMode is True if there is an icon instead of line text
      data[n][m] = null;
    } else {
      String text = new String("<html><p>" + labelArray.get(n + m).lineOne + "<br>" + labelArray.get(n + m).lineTwo + "<p></html>");
      data[n][m] = text;
    }
  }
}

table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
renderer.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

for (int n = 0; n < tableWidth; n++) {
  table.getColumnModel().getColumn(n).setCellRenderer(renderer);
  table.getColumnModel().getColumn(n).setWidth(50);
}
```

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but I know that many find it much easier answering questions if the poster creates and displays a valid [mcve] program with their question.

Comment: You will need to create a (possibly anonymous) subclass of DefaultTableCellRenderer and override its [getTableCellRendererComponent method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable,java.lang.Object,boolean,boolean,int,int)).  See [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) in the Java tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there could be an ImageIcon, String or both.

You will need to create a custom object to store in the TableModel. This object will contain two properties:

1. text
2. icon

Then you will need to create a custom renderer (not use the default renderer) to display this object.

The custom renderer might look something like:

```
class IconTextRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    public IconTextRenderer()
    {
        super();
        setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        IconText iconText = (IconText)value;
        setIcon( iconText.getIcon() );
        setText( iconText.getText() );

        return this;
    }
}
```

You set the renderer for a single column by using:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(???).setCellRenderer( new IconTextRenderer());
```

or for all columns using the custom class:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(IconText.class, new IconTextRenderer());
```