# How to put text next to my ImageIcon on a cell in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel, imageicon

I have an application that works with a `JTable`, and in this `JTable`, I want each cell to have both an `ImageIcon` and some text.

I see at this link (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), `JTable` supports `ImageIcon` OR text, but seemingly not both at the same time.

I also see that on the bullet for `ImageIcon`, it says ***rendered by a centered label***.

Well, I know for a fact that I can put both an `ImageIcon` and text together on the same `JLabel` -- I am doing that already for a different part of my application.

How do I get access to that `JLabel`, so that I can put some text alongside that icon?

Comment: Probably going to be easier to create your own renderer with the technique you're already using elsewhere

Comment: @g00se I agree, and I figured as much. I'm happy to try implementing a renderer, but I'm ignorant about them.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52065145/131872

Comment: @camickr Perfect, ty vm. In that case, my question is a duplicate. I've flagged it as such. If you or someone else could help the question along to being closed, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hmmmm, actually, I think I can add a good answer to my question that carries a few more details than yours. Typing it up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been informed that my question is actually a duplicate. Here is a link to the original question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52065145/131872

But I can provide a bit more detail to how I implemented it for me.

In my case, I want to store both an `ImageIcon` and some text. So, the first thing I should do is create a data type that contains both of these elements.

```java
record TextIcon(String text, ImageIcon icon) {}
```

Next, I need to create a renderer that can render this data type. To do that, I will extend the [`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html).

```java
   
      final class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
      {
      
         @Override
         public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
         {
         
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
         
            if (value instanceof TextIcon textIcon)
            {
            
               this.setText(textIcon.text());
               this.setIcon(textIcon.icon());
            
            }
         
            return this;
         
         }
      }
```

Doing it this way is nice because, now, I don't need to specify which column this applies to. I can apply this renderer to all of my columns, and then if they are not a `TextIcon`, they will just do the default rendering they would have gotten.

Alternatively, if I need to create another data type for my table, I can just add another if statement to this method. This strategy is a powerful way to add custom rendering to your table.

Now that I have my renderer, I will add it to all of my columns. Here is the easiest way to do it.

```java
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyTableCellRenderer());
```

I use `Object.class` because I want this renderer to be used for all columns. Since `Object` is a parent to all reference data types, then doing this essentially means that I am applying this renderer to all of my columns.

After that, I just continue as is, and things just work!

Comment: *I use Object.class because I want this renderer to be used for all columns.* -  Yes the default implementation of the DefaultTableModel returns Object.class, but a better implementation is to override the getColumnClass() method to return the class type for the column. This allows the table to choose the appropriate renderer. For example Boolean values will be rendered as a check box (not true/false) numeric values will be right aligned. Adding nested if/else statements to the renderer is not the best approach. A renderer should be reusable for any table.

Comment: @camickr That's fair, ty. I agree, it does clump things together. My plan was to actually use the new pattern-matching for switch feature, hence why I wanted them all in the same renderer, then just switch on the type.

Comment: *pattern-matching for switch feature* - don't know what that is but I still don't like the sound of it. Advice should be generic. A renderer should do a single job. For example, what if your table has two columns with Double values. One is a dollar amount and the other is a percentage amount. Now class can't be used to format the data you also need the column. Instead use custom reusable renderers. Check out [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for a flexible approach.

Comment: @camickr -- It's a new feature that is coming out for Java this September in Java 21. They have been previewing it since for about a year now, and it is coming out for real late-September. Here is a link to the JEP itself. https://openjdk.org/jeps/441