Add ImageIcon + text to JLabel
I would like to add an image and some text to the cell of a JTable.
Here is the GUI class that seems to cause problems:
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class GUITable extends JFrame {
    private TableData boardData;
    private int lines;
    private int cols;

    public GUITable(TableData boardData) {
        this.boardData = boardData;
        this.lines = 10;
        this.cols = 9;


        setTitle("title");
        setSize(500, 450);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(500, 450);
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                return Object.class;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                if (value instanceof ImageIcon) {
                    JLabel label = new JLabel((ImageIcon) value);
                    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    return label;
                }
                return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                int valeur = 5;
                String text = "random text";
                table.setValueAt(text, i, j);
            }
        }
        DefaultTableModel smallTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(3, 1);
        JTable smallTable = new JTable(smallTableModel) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                return Object.class;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomTableRenderer());
        smallTable.setValueAt("1", 0, 0);
        smallTable.setValueAt("2", 1, 0);
        smallTable.setValueAt("3", 2, 0);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.add(smallTable);
        panel.add(table);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

        add(scrollPane);

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int key = e.getKeyCode();
                boolean moved = false;

                switch (key) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                        moved = boardData.moveCharacter(0, -1);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                        moved = boardData.moveCharacter(0, 1);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        moved = boardData.moveCharacter(-1, 0);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        moved = boardData.moveCharacter(1, 0);
                        break;
                }

                if (moved) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                            int valeur = 5;
                            String text "random text";
                            table.setValueAt(text, i, j);
                        }
                    }

                    updateData(boardData);
                }
            }
        });

        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void updateData(TableData newBoardData) {
        this.boardData = newBoardData;
        setSize(500, 450);
        JTable table = (JTable) ((JPanel) ((JScrollPane) getContentPane().getComponent(0)).getViewport().getView()).getComponent(1);
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

        tableModel.setRowCount(lines);
        tableModel.setColumnCount(cols);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                int value = 5;
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                if(value < 0){
                    panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/random1"))));
                } else if (value > 0){
                    panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/random2"))));
                }
                panel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(value)));
                table.setValueAt(panel, i, j);
            }
        }

        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();

        JTable smallTable = (JTable) ((JPanel) ((JScrollPane) getContentPane().getComponent(0)).getViewport().getView()).getComponent(0);

        smallTable.setValueAt("1", 0, 0);
        smallTable.setValueAt("2", 1, 0);
        smallTable.setValueAt("3", 2, 0);
    }
    private class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (value instanceof ImageIcon) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel((ImageIcon) value);
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                return label;
            }
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        }
    }
}

I've come up with a CustomTableRenderer:
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CustomTableRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        setOpaque(true);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);


        setIcon(null);
        setText("");

        if (value instanceof String) {
            String text = (String) value;
            setText(text);
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            int intValue = (Integer) value;
            if (intValue < 0) {
                System.out.println("test");
                setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/randomimage1.png")));
            } else if (intValue > 0) {
                System.out.println("test 2");
                setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/randomimage2.png")));
            }
            setText(String.valueOf(intValue));
        }
        return this;
    }
}

The images folder is in src. I didn't add the details of TableData because it doesn't seem useful since the problem comes from the display system.
My problem is that every cell only displays a value and no images. CustomTableRenderer is never reached.
Could someone help me understand what's wrong in my code?

A JPanel is not a type of cell value that a JTable knows how to render.  You will have to create your own cell renderer.  (By the way, you don’t need a JPanel at all;  a single JLabel is already capable of displaying both text and an icon.)

Thank you. How can I iterate on the table with a cell renderer? The values I would like to display depend on an array with the same dimensions as the table.

How can I iterate on the table with a cell renderer? -  You create a custom renderer. The custom renderer will get the data from the model and set the text/icon of the renderer appropriately. For example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52065145/131872

I can't seem to find a way to adapt this to my code. And how can I only use JLabels?

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the How To Use Tables section.  It's long and detailed.
The code fragment posted in the question did not provide enough information to determine the cause of your problem.  So, I went ahead and created a minimal reproducible example.
Here's what the GUI looks like.

Each cell of the JTable has an image and a value.
I created a TableCellRenderer to display the image and value.  JTables have many additional classes to support the JTable functionality.  That's why I said study the Oracle tutorial.
Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class TableCellRendererExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TableCellRendererExample());
    }

    private final ApplicationModel applicationModel;

    private JTable table;

    public TableCellRendererExample() {
        this.applicationModel = new ApplicationModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableCellRendere Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createTablePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTablePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        int[][] array = applicationModel.getArray();
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        tableModel.setRowCount(array.length);
        tableModel.setColumnCount(array[0].length);
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
                tableModel.setValueAt(array[row][col], row, col);
            }
        }

//      System.out.println(tableModel.getValueAt(0, 0).getClass());

        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        ExampleTableCellRenderer renderer = new ExampleTableCellRenderer();
        for (int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++) {
            TableColumn tc = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col);
            tc.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        }

//      table.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, new ExampleTableCellRenderer());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    public class ExampleTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        private JLabel label = new JLabel();

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
//          label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.TRAILING);
            label.setText(Integer.toString((Integer) value));
            int intValue = (Integer) value;

            if (intValue < 0) {
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(applicationModel.getRedImage()));
            } else if (intValue > 0) {
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(applicationModel.getGreenImage()));
            }

            return label;
        }

    }

    public class ApplicationModel {

        private final int[][] array;

        private final BufferedImage greenImage, redImage;

        private final Random random;

        public ApplicationModel() {
            this.greenImage = createImage(Color.GREEN);
            this.redImage = createImage(Color.RED);
            this.random = new Random();
            this.array = new int[10][10];

            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
                    array[row][col] = random.nextInt(-10, 21);
                }
            }
        }

        private BufferedImage createImage(Color color) {
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(16, 32,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            g.dispose();

            return image;
        }

        public int[][] getArray() {
            return array;
        }

        public BufferedImage getGreenImage() {
            return greenImage;
        }

        public BufferedImage getRedImage() {
            return redImage;
        }

    }

}


Thank you. I posted a more concrete example.
